# Как работать с мултитач на Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Например так: нажал на левую сторону экрана - вывелось "Hi", а на правую - "Bye". Когда обе нажал - "Good". Некоторые советуют количество пальцев считать, а мне надо чтобы в определенных участках были нажатия. Если два пальца с правой стороны экрана тапнуть, всё равно "Bye" должно вывести. Это как пример. Мне нужно понять как реализуется. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать зоны и интерфейсы [IPointerDownHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) и [IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html). (для их работы на сцене должен быть скрипт `EventSystem` - он создаётся автоматически при создании первого `Canvas`)

Первый срабатывает, когда произошло нажатие на объект, на котором висит скрипт, а второй, когда оно закончилось.

Условно, самая простая реализация следующая - делаете две прозрачные картинки в нужных вам местах. Вешаете на них скрипты, которые реализуют эти два интерфейса. Делаете общий класс отвечающий за выведение вашего текста и имеющий две `bool` переменные - `isLeft` и `isRight`.

Когда `IPointerDownHandler` срабатывает - меняете соответствующий стороне срабатывания `bool` на `true`, после чего проверяете оба `bool` и выводите соответствующий текст.

Соответственно при срабатывании `IPointerUpHandler` - меняете соответствующий `bool` на `false` и опять проверяете переменные и меняете текст.